# How to restrict read only *.mxd file?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have an *.mxd file and I don't want to save any edits to it after each session. Is there a way in 'arcpy' or python in general to restrict edit of *.mxd file? Any suggestions would be appreciative.

Comment: A workaround could be to copy your mxd to a subfolder. Everytime you (or someone else) accidentally saves it, just replace with your copy.

Comment: Just make it readonly in the filesystem (windows explorer).

Comment: @Martin: Just a thought -- I have to double click on *.mxd to open it. How would that work with even making a new copy?

Comment: @BradHards: I tried `attrib +r C:\temp\file.mxd' but it pop ups 'Save As' dialog to the same folder where original file is placed. I can use this option unless there is a way to set a different default path.

Comment: Why would double clicking be an issue in the making of a copy? Anyway, you can always open your (same) mxd two times at once, then you won't be able to save any changes. But all of these are just rough workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can [save your mxd as a template](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000002w000000). When you create a new document from a template, an untitled map is opened based on the selected template. You must save your mxd in %APPDATA%\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Templates so it's available in the list of templates in ArcMap.